# How to add menus/ subtopics for meteor site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, url-routing, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor. I followed the tutorials and successfully making simple interfaces like below. I tried finding examples to add menus/ subtopics like [this](http://generator-subpages.meteor.com) which does not reload the page when clicked, but I couldn't find any examples. Could you please give me an example how to do this?

in **simple-todos.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>
    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

in **simple-todos.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [IronRouter](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) ([Guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md)) or [FlowRouter](https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router) package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this functionality using [meteor-useraccounts](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core) package. [Here](http://useraccounts-bootstrap.meteor.com/) is live example of this package.

You can go through its complete [documentation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) for your understanding.